# Force docker to cache git clone command

Tags: git, docker, http

I have this in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:teros/datavana.git
```

the problem I am experiencing is that it will re-run the clone command frequently - I believe because if the network responses indicate that there are any new commits, it will re-clone everything and won't use the cache.

Is there some way to force this step to use the cache? 
Perhaps just use a multi-stage build?

Comment: On its own Docker will cache this step (the usual complaint about `RUN git clone` in fact is that it is cached and doesn’t see recent commits; the usual best practice is to not run this in a Dockerfile).  Some line before this is probably invalidating the cache.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, I have an ARG command before that, that's invalidating the cache. How can I move the git clone out of the Dockerfile? Looking for something that's easily automated.

Comment: Please paste the entire dockerfile and we can provide feedback on improving caching

Comment: `I have an ARG command before that, that's invalidating the cache`, are you sure this will invalid the cache? Post reproduce-able dockerfile not let folks to guess please...